# How to collect images and text from pdf catalogue in javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[sample pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8Ji.png)[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8Ji.png)
In this catalog there are 4 images and 5 description and a title and price. I need to collect all these things from the image by using JavaScript. Help in this regard will be appreciated
// script

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var processor = document.getElementById("processor");
var output = document.getElementById("output");


window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if (event.source != processor.contentWindow) return;


    switch (event.data){
        case "ready":
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            xhr.onload = function(event) {
                processor.contentWindow.postMessage(this.response, "*");
            };
            xhr.send();
            break;


        default:
            output.textContent = event.data.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            break;
    }
}, true);
```

// these code got from net- to collect text from pdf , i need to collect images also.

```
// embed the pdftotext web app as an iframe

<iframe id="processor" src="http://hubgit.github.com/2011/11/pdftotext/"></iframe>

// a container for the output -->

<div id="output"><div id="intro">Extracting text from a PDF file using only Javascript.<br>Tested in Chrome 16 and Firefox 9.</div></div>
```

//  the PDF file must be on the same domain as this page -->

Comment: Post what you have tried! and correct image.

Comment: add your code to get some idea

Comment: Hi, I am trying to collect images and text from a PDF catalogue , using javascript or AngularJS. i had posted one sample image , that image contain 4 items and their description, am trying to collect it from pdf please help me

Comment: Do not add code to the comments. Instead update your question with the code (and only the code necessary for the relevant part of the question).